search('map <F\d>.','W') fails to find pattern in my .vimrc
Mostly I invoke my key-mappings with a function key followed by a single character.
Finding an unused combination gets tedious, so I'm writing a mapping to list all such combinations in my .vimrc
But trying :echo search('map <F\d>.','W') consistently returns 0,
whereas /map F<\d>. works as expected.
If I reduce the search pattern by removing characters from the RH end, it works as expected with :echo search('map <F','W') which first made me think the regex search engine had got lost, but doing :echo search('\a- *\a','W') works perfectly to find hyphenated words.
Does anyone else have this problem?

Problem: too many mappings. Solution: one more mapping.

Both / and search() search forward, starting from the current line.
/ honors :help 'wrapscan', which is probably enabled in your case, while search('pattern', 'W') explicitly tells Vim to not wrap around. So, if the cursor is somehow below the last <Fn> mapping, then you get a 0. You can either drop the W so that it can restart the search from the top of the buffer if it doesn't find anything or explicitly place your cursor on line 1 before you search() with something like call cursor(1, 1).
But that's a a red herring anyway, because you should use maparg() or maplist() instead. Those functions don't care about cursor position, search wrapping, or even if the mappings are defined in your vimrc.
To list all <Fn> mappings—and all their details—, do:
function! ListAllFnMappings()
    return maplist()
           \ ->filter({idx, val -> val.lhs =~ '^<F\d>'})
endfunction

For a more usable, :map-like, output:
function! CleanUpNotation(in)
    if a:in == ' '
        return 'nvo'
    elseif a:in == '!'
        return 'ic'
    else
        return a:in
    endif
endfunction
function! ListAllFnMappings()
    return maplist()
           \ ->filter({ idx, val -> val.lhs =~ '^<F\d>' })
           \ ->sort({ item1, item2 -> item1.lhs > item2.lhs })
           \ ->map({ idx, val -> CleanUpNotation(val.mode) .. ' ' .. val.lhs .. ' ' .. val.rhs .. "\n" })
           \ ->join('')
endfunction

which, in my case, prints this:
n <F5> <Plug>(qf_qf_toggle)
n <F6> <Plug>(qf_loc_toggle)

To know if a given key sequence is free, do:
maparg('<F5>')->empty()

which returns 1 (true) if <F5> is free and 0 (false) if there is already a mapping on <F5>.
See :help maplist() and :help maparg() for the nitty-gritty.

To have comparable result I'll do:
:echo search('map <F\d>.')

Unless you have:
set nowrapscan

In which case to have comparable result you should indeed do:
:echo search('map <F\d>.', 'W')

